# org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client: how to get exception stacktrace generated in spark code

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I am running a Spark application with `org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client`. I would like to collect the exceptions generated by the spark code, so that I can send them by email. I've tryed surrounding the code with a try catch like the following:

```
try{
   ClientArguments clientArguments = new ClientArguments(args, sparkConf);
   Client client = new Client(clientArguments, hadoopConf, sparkConf);
   client.run();
}
catch (Exception e) {
   System.out.println(e);
}
```

but the application print something like

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Application application_1460365288125_171742 finished with failed status
```

and not the actual exception, so to retrieve the real exception I have to access the log. I've browsed the web but I couldn't find any solution nor workaround. Does anybody know a possible solution?

**EDIT:**

More generally, the question is:

Given an application id (e.g. application_1454432703118_3634), how can I **programmatically** get any exception thrown during the application?

Comment: You want to print the exception to the console? Or by get do you mean collect it as a log file?

Comment: To debug it I was trying to print it in the console, but the final solution would be to send it by email.